# document.body.style.color = 'blue'; document.body.style.fontSize = 18px'; does not work in Android WebKit

Tags: javascript, android, css, dom, webkit

I have been trying to inject the following code into Android webkit, but it does not have any effect

```
document.body.style.color = 'blue'; 
document.body.style.fontSize = '18px';
```

on the other hand the following DOM method works

```
document.body.style.BackgroundColor = 'green';
```

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S running Android Froyo. This colour and fontSize methods work on regular web based Safari browsers but I am nt having any luck with the Android webkit browsers. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

In case these methods are not supported by Android webkit, is there any way i can determine which DOM methods and properties are supported by my WebKit based browser and which are not?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Have you tried setting the values using CSS instead?

Comment: I created http://jsfiddle.net/sQK4t/ and opened the result frame ( http://fiddle.jshell.net/sQK4t/show/ ) in my Android browser (Galaxy S with Android 2.3.3) and it seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are the body element's direct child elements (e.g. ) absolutely positioned? If so then the document has no height (don't ask me why), you will need to give it height to give it a background color.

If you insist on doing inline styling then have you tried...

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = '#00f';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontSize= '18px';
```

Comment: What makes you think that your example is more correct than the OP's? If it's the use of `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]` instead of `document.body`, then I'm sorely tempted to down vote this answer.